# UV Texturing has unwanted seams

Tags: texturing

I have this problem where if I apply an image texture it gets oddly distorted or doesn't line up. I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here are 2 images showing what I mean.

[image]

[image]

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: we don't know enough about your image or UV map, please show some screenshots or pack the image and share your file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/